# An efficient way to convert JObject to class with Automapper (C#)

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to convert JSON to a custom object, I'm using AutoMapper to do it. This is my code and it currently works:

```
public string json = @"
{
  'index': 'dagger',
  'name': 'Dagger',
  'equipment_category': 'weapon'
}"

public class Equipment
{
  public string Index { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string EquipmentCategory { get; set; }
}

public Equipment Convert()
{
  var config = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
  {
    config.CreateMap<JObject, Equipment>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Index, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["index"])
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["name"])
      .ForMember(dest => dest.EquipmentCategory, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["equipment_category"])
  }
  var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
  var result = mapper.Map<Equipment>(JObject.Parse(json));

  return result;
}
```

The downside of this is that I have to create a `ForMember` rule for every property in the object. Does anyone know of a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Automapper to convert the json to a POCO (Equipment class). Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)` along with `JsonPropertyAttribute`. The "mapping" will be taken care for you using the Newtonsoft deserializer.

```
public class Equipment
{
    [JsonProperty("index")]
    public string Index { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("equipment_category")]
    public string EquipmentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize to POCO

```
string json = @"
{
  'index': 'dagger',
  'name': 'Dagger',
  'equipment_category': 'weapon'
}"
var equipment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Equipment>(json);
```

Once you have a POCO instance, Automapper becomes handy to map this class to another POCO.

```
var result = mapper.Map<EquipmentDto>(equipment);
```

Newtonsoft Serializing and Deserializing JSON
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: If for some reason you already have a JObject instead of a string, then `obj.ToObject<Equipment>()`

Comment: While I understand why OP marked this answer as being correct, Jeremy's comment above is actually the answer to the question posed.  The original question isn't how do I deserialize a JSON string to a C# POCO, it's how do I convert JObject to POCO.